# VBA Adding rowfields into Pivot table

Tags: vba, excel, row, pivot-table

I would like to use combination of macros and slicer to switch different Rowfields in one Pivot table. I already have this code to choose different datafields. It is placed not in a Module but in the specific list in VBA editor. In that list in my excel there is a secondary Pivot table controlled by slicer where I choose what should be displayed in datafields of the main Pivot table.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

Dim ptMain As PivotTable
Dim pfMeasure As PivotField
Dim i As Long

On Error GoTo Errorhandler

Set ptMain = Worksheets("Multidimensional Graph").PivotTables("Multidimensional")

For Each pfMeasure In ptMain.DataFields
    pfMeasure.Orientation = xlHidden
Next

'to be able to choose more than one datafield
i = 0
Do While [ChoiceMeasures].Offset(i, 0).Value <> ""
    ptMain.AddDataField ptMain.PivotFields([ChoiceMeasures].Offset(i, 0).Value), [ChoiceMeasures] & " ", xlSum
    i = i + 1
Loop
Exit Sub    
Errorhandler:
Debug.Print Now(), Err.Description

End Sub
```

Now I would like to change Rows instead of values. For example there are Products displayed in rows and its volume sold in datafields. I can change it to sales in $ displayed in datafields using method above but I would also like to change to displaying our Customers (in rows) and their volume or sales. 
I tried it like that (modifying the macro for datafields):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate2(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

Dim ptMain As PivotTable
Dim pfDimension As PivotField
Dim i As Long

On Error GoTo Errorhandler

Set ptMain = Worksheets("Multidimensional Graph").PivotTables("Multidimensional")

For Each pfDimension In ptMain.RowFields
    pfDimension.Orientation = xlHidden
Next

ptMain.PivotFields([ChoiceDimensions]).Orientation = xlRowField

Exit Sub

Errorhandler:
Debug.Print Now(), Err.Description

End Sub
```

but it does not work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: "It is placed not in a Module but in the specific list in VBA editor" - I don't understand what that means. Can you explain please? It is an event so will go in the relevant code pane for the sheet.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I mean that the code above is inserted in the sheet tab (first red line in the picture) and not in Module tab (second line). I have always written macros in Modules so I have no experience with codes in those sheet tabs so I wanted to mention it    https://ibb.co/enX45S